# django + angularjs resource + ajax POST = 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: ajax, django, post, angularjs

I can do GET requests, but when I do POST, in Chrome developer tools I see: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)"

I thought the problem is in Django's csrf_token, so I found this solution:

```
.config(function($httpProvider){
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRFToken'] = CSRF_TOKEN;
});
```

In my `index.html`, in `<head>` I have:

```
<script>
    CSRF_TOKEN = '{{ csrf_token }}';
</script>
```

But it still raises 500 error. Am I doing something wrong or the problem is not in csrf?

P.S. `CSRF_TOKEN` is declared before

```
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

and other scripts.

Comment: 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR isn't too helpful. What's the exact error that Django throws?

Comment: @Blender, how can I see it? I suppose I need some `error` function in Angular

Comment: Problem was solved by using $http instead of $resource

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've figured out the problem.

Django by default appends slash to your URL. If you enter:

`http://mydjangosite.com/page` Django will redirect you to: `http://mydjangosite.com/page/`

Angular's `$resource` removes trailing slash (you can read about it on github: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/992).

> Django has APPEND_SLASH setting which uses HTTP 302 redirection to
>   append slash to urls without slash. This works with GET method but not
>   with others (POST,PUT,DELETE) because redirection cannot and will not
>   pass the data to the new URL

So, there are two options:

1) Use `$http` insread of `$resource`

or

2) In Django's `settings.py` add this line:

```
APPEND_SLASH = False
```

and in your `urls.py` remove all trailing slashes

Answer (score 0):

simply escape the backslash like: /custom_api/get_nearest_hotels/:eventId\/

(From: http://pragmaticstartup.wordpress.com/2013/04/27/some-lessons-learnt-from-messing-with-django-and-angularjs/)

Answer (score 0):

As you all know you need to dump dictionary in your HTTPRESPONCE object.

sometimes what happens, in your view; you try to dump something in to your dict that can not be serialized. that is python/django can not serialize that object.

the examples can be (FORM OBJECT), (MODEL OBJECT), etc

so you need to get those away.

```
context = {}
context['office_form'] = OfficeCompleteForm(request.POST)
```

this can not be serialized and you will get 500 error.

be free to add following data.

```
 context['success'] = {"msg": "successfully updated. "}
 context['error'] = {"msg": "error can not update. "}
```

and at last do not forget to call you response method like this.

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(context), content_type="application/json")
```